# Access property of class not declared by interface

Tags: vb.net, class, interface

How can I access a property of a class which is not declared in the interface it implements?

```
Interface IMyInterface

    Property MyInterfaceProperty As String

End Interface

Public Class MyImplementingClass
    Implements IMyInterface

    Public Property MyClassProperty As String

    Public Property MyInterfaceProperty As String Implements IMyInterface.MyInterfaceProperty
End Class

Public Class MyTestClass

    Public Sub New()
        Dim foo As IMyInterface = New MyImplementingClass
        foo.MyInterfaceProperty = "foo"
        foo.MyClassProperty = "bar" '### Compile Error MyClassProperty is not a member of IMyInterface
    End Sub

End Class
```

I've tried adding

```
foo = CType(foo, MyImplementingClass)
```

but it doesn't work...

Comment: You *shouldn't*, that's the point of using an interface.  If `foo` should be of type `MyImplementingClass` then declare it as `Dim foo As MyImplementingClass`.  If you *must* then you should be able to cast it: `(CType(foo, MyImplementingClass)).MyClassProperty`  But this defeats the purpose of an interface in the first place, so why bother with this workaround and just use the type you need.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Either declare it as implementing the interface, or declare it as being the class.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification guys. My example was First one to add it as an answer gets the point :)

Comment: I'll try that again... Thanks for the clarification guys. My example was over simplified but your comments helped to steer me onto a different track. First one to add it as an answer gets the points :)